# With vim, how can I use autocmd's for files in subdirectories of a specific path?

Tags: vim

I am trying to figure out how I can define an autocmd that influences all files under a specific path.

The autocmd I have tried is something like

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /specificPath/** imap <buffer> ....
```

Now, I'd expect this autocmd to be used if I edited, say, /foo/bar/specificPath/baz/something/bla.txt, but not if I edited /foo/bar/here/and/there/moreBla.txt

If I start vim being in a directory 'above' specificPath, this works as I want it. But it doesn't if I am below that directory. Obviously, the autocmd's pattern is matched against the relative file name, not the absolute one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So, I've done this in my code with paths under a particular path. You need to do:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile */somepath/* set filetype=sometype
```

At least, that's what I was using to set a given filetype for things under a particular library path. Hopefully that will help with your example.

If you want to include all subdirectories, use `**`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile */somepath/** set filetype=sometype
```

Comment: That was stupid of me, I should have thought about the asterik in front of the pattern...

Comment: what if I wanna give absolute paths and not part of a path ?
like `/home/user/work/` will there be a preceding asterisk?

Comment: I think there's a way of doing that too - just miss out the leading * in the list. You probably need the leading / if you want to match somethng like /home, though.

Comment: `*/somedir/*` doesn't actually seem to work for subdirectories. Has anybody else happened upon an answer? Thanks!

Comment: As a casual perusal of `:h autocmd-patterns` would show, `*/somedir/*` *does* work as expected. Hence, this being the accepted answer is entirely sensible. Here's why this works: whereas the `*` quantifier in shell glob patterns match 0 or more characters *excluding* directory separators, the `*` quantifier in vim `autocmd` patterns match 0 or more characters *including* directory separators.

Comment: `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile */backup/* set directory=$HOME/.vim/swapfiles//` seems not to prevent the creation of .swp files in my /backup/ when I edit ~/backup/example.txt

Answer (score 18):

VIM's inbuilt help will answer all your questions. :)

```
:h autocmd-pattern
```

Comment: honestly, I found this more useful than the accepted answer so I threw an upvote your way. next time, try providing an example or quoted text from the documentation!